# What should I do when at the end of the running times in NetLogo the model stop working?

Tags: netlogo

I was running a model in NetLogo 5.3.1 through behavior space for 5000 timesteps and 100 times run. I set output as a spreadsheet. However, the running time stop at 93 and 5000 timesteps for 24 hours. The clock of the model works and the commend on updating the view and plots also works. What should I do? should I wait for more than 24 hours? should I abort the order? or there is any other solution to not losing the data. The model has worked for about 700 hours.

Answer (score 1):

a) BehaviorSpace can look like it's stopped while it's still running-- as long as the total time clock is still increasing, it's still running.

b) If you want to see how it is doing, find the BehaviorSpace output file, make a copy of it, and open the copy. If you do that two times, you can confirm that it's still running.

c) The "Spreadsheet" output format is usually a bad idea. It uses up a great deal of memory and the file is usually harder to use than the "table" format. Sometimes a BehaviorSpace experiment can crash because the spreadsheet output file used up all the computer's RAM.